# How can I use belongsto with concat?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, belongs-to

I try :

```
public function sa()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Sajd::class, 'CONCAT(code_sa,code_jd)', 'code_sajd');
}
```

But, seems it's wrong

How can I do it correctly?

Comment: Not sure you can use `belongsTo` with anything other than simple keys. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @apokryfos, There exist error : `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: There's not enough information. Can you provide some more detail? Is this code in a model?